# wifi options not being set to disable power / how to reload wifi setting changes without rebooting

Tags: 16.04, wireless, power-management, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

My wifi options are not being set to disable power save / how to reload wifi setting changes without rebooting.  I'm using a intel 7260ac card

I change the parameter in my **iwlwifi.conf** file with

**options iwlwifi power_save=2** and also type in **sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off** at the terminal screen but my power_save option always says enabled.

**parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)**

```
$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep -v 'pci:' | grep -v 'iwlwifi-'

$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep -v 'pci:' | grep -v 'iwlwifi-'
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
srcversion:     E7651FD3D9AF45F96CD8B2E
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-41-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
$ 

$ uname -a
Linux sys76 4.8.0-41-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 17:11:16 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0f2  no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"2.4ghz"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: E0:3F:49:93:3F:10   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:6  Invalid misc:248   Missed beacon:0
```

And is there way to restart wifi and have the changes take place if I make changes to the iwlwifi.conf file without rebooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

to disable power management for wifi.  Reboot and the power management should remain off.  The results of `modinfo iwlwifi` does not reflect any changes made by module options in the /etc/modprobe.d/ conf files use

```
grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/*
```

To see those changes
Changes to the conf file can be loaded by removing and reinstalling the driver
`sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` wait ten seconds and `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`